# Why the back button stopped to work on my Phonegap app after showing admob banner on android?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, cordova-admob, phonegap-admob

I coded an app with phonegap and framework7. Everything was fine, including my physical back button that is used to navigate and prompt a confirm box before exiting the app.

Finally, I included the admob's code, which I already used before but in an app that doesn't used the back button. And when I launched it on play store (I only get the ads to show in production), once the bottom banner appears, the back button automatically close the app, instantly. It stopped to work completely.

After further investigation I discovered that the focus are on the banner and not on the app (like an iframe), so the back button is caught by the ad and not my the app. When I click on the ad and go to the ad content, if I get back to the app the back button works fine.

My problem is exactly like [this one](https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free/issues/19), but I tried his solution without success. I found the right file and changed the line as he said, but the issue remained.

Does anyone already experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it by using another plugin, the [cordova-plugin-admob-free](https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free).